# Android App font size (dp)

Tags: android, html, css

I am currently building an app and would like to automatically adjust the font size to the field of view (window). I read the data via a database (HTML code) and if I deposit a fixed px number, this is mostly ok on large devices, but on a small scale too small. How can I fix the problem? Can I store css class for the individual texts and use the e.g. to combine with dp from android? Because dp adapts to the resolution of the window.

How would I implement this?

Hope somebody has a good solution for me.

Best regards

Comment: I for one am not really sure what you're saying. If you're doing this in a WebView or native app, on the website then thinking of adjusting on Android, etc. My best thought is to do something like what swiping to resize text does or using the newer auto text resizing. There's multiple ways on doing text size and whatever you think is best for you should be what you do.